# Why is the model predicting the same class label for all inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My model is always outputting the same class label for all the inputs

Here is the model

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = image_shape)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size = 5)(input)
layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64,kernel_size = 5)(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1024,activation='ReLU')(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.4)(layer)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 43,activation='softmax')(layer)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input],outputs = [output])
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True), optimizer = 'sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'] )
history = model.fit(train_x,train_y,validation_data = (valid_x,valid_y), epochs = 2)
```

The loss is always coming around 3.5 and decreases very slowly

One of the only preprocessing I am doing is grayscaling,reshaping and normalizing

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.transform import resize
image_shape = (32,32,1)
number_label = 43

def reshape_and_grayscale(dataset):
  i = 0
  for data in dataset :
    image_data = data[0]
    
    if len(image_data.shape) > 2 :
      image_data = rgb2gray(image_data)
      
    image_data = resize(image_data,image_shape)
    dataset[i][0] = image_data/255 # normalizing : dividing by 255
    i+=1
```

For one hot encoding I am using tf.one_hot for indiviual images

```
y[i] = tf.one_hot(int(data[1]),depth = number_label)
```

The database I am using is GTSRB database.

Answer (score 0):

without going into your code in details, few things you might want to consider:

1. substract mean value before normalized by 255.0
2. running more epoch for training (fitting)
3. how many images for training? consider having bigger dataset for training
4. since your input image only has resolution of 32x32, consider to reduce kernel size from 5 to 3 to see if there is better chance to pickup more features in details.

Comment: I changed the optimizer from sgd to adam and it is working correctly now.How did changing the optimizer affected the loss so greatly?

Comment: well, the whole idea of optimizer is "a random walk (guided by gradient) in a very high dimensional space and hopefully to find the minimal loss position". There is no guarantee which optimizer can "hit" the minimal loss point. In your case, adam might hit the sweet spot faster than sgd without tweeting some advanced parameters. To read more, you may take a look of this article (https://medium.com/geekculture/a-2021-guide-to-improving-cnns-optimizers-adam-vs-sgd-495848ac6008#:~:text=SGD%20is%20better%3F,results%20in%20improved%20final%20performance.)...